# Find the probability that an article chosen at random from lot C is defective

Tags: probability

> - Lot A contains 6 good and 4 defective articles.
> - Lot B contains 7 good and 3 defective articles.
>
> A new lot C is formed by taking 6 articles from lot A and 4 articles from lot B.
>   Find the probability that an article chosen at random from lot C is defective.

*It is leading to too many cases*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just weight the probabilities of defectiveness from each of the original lots (A and B) with the probabilities of an item in lot C coming from A or from B.

That is,

\begin{align}
P(\text{an item from $C$ is defective}) = P(\text{the item was selected from } A)P(\text{an item from $A$ is defective})\newline+P(\text{the item was selected from } B)P(\text{an item from $B$ is defective})
\end{align}

Comment: Continuing from where you left off           $=\frac{3}{5}.\frac{2}{5}+\frac{2}{5}.\frac{3}{10}=\frac{9}{25}$